# Java JComponent doesn't refresh

Tags: java, swing, colors, components, jcomponent

I've got problem with my class Component. The problem is that my ovals doesn't changing their colors. The function if is observing OVF flag in class Counter. when OVF=true ovals should be red, and when OVF=false ovals should be white. in my GUI i can see only red ovals (even if OVF=false). I try to add repaint() command but red ovals only started blinking. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Observable;


public class Komponent extends JComponent
{
Counter counter3;
public Komponent()
{
    counter3=new Counter();
}
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
 Graphics2D dioda = (Graphics2D)g;
 int x1 = 85;
 int x2 = 135;
 int y = 3;
 int width = (getSize().width/9)-6;
 int height = (getSize().height-1)-6;

 if (counter3.OVF = true)
 {
 dioda.setColor(Color.RED);
 dioda.fillOval(x1, y, width, height);
 dioda.fillOval(x2, y, width, height);
 }
if (counter3.OVF = false)
{
 dioda.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 dioda.fillOval(x1, y, width, height);
 dioda.fillOval(x2, y, width, height);
}
}
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
 new Komponent();
}
}
```

what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Don't override paint, its recommended that you use paintComponent instead. You should also be call super.paintComponent (or super.paint in your case). Check out [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If should be:

```
if (counter3.OVF == true) { // watch out for = and ==
    // red
}
if (counter3.OVF == false) {
    // white
}
```

Or simpler:

```
if (counter3.OVF) {
    // red
} else {
    // white
}
```

Or simplest:

```
dioda.setColor(counter3.OVF ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
dioda.fillOval(x1, y, width, height);
dioda.fillOval(x2, y, width, height);
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right. But now the oval is still white, maybe i should add repaint() function.

Comment: All of your answers are good, thank you :) but still i can only see white ovals :(

Comment: @user2283763 try `System.out.println(counter3.OVF);` in `paint`, to check the value of `counter3.OVF`.

Comment: i've got it and when i count up and it's overflow, the flag OVF is set to true